# How come the HTML onclick does not call my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, my JavaScript function is not working. I want to use onclick on an h1 tag. On the snippet below, it works just fine. But when I try it on Chrome, it doesn't do anything. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function loginDetails() {
    alert("Username: somebody\nPassword: pass123");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Screen</title>
        <link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="login.js">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 onclick="loginDetails()">Login</h1>
            <form>
                <label for="username" class="label-1">Username</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="text-box"><br>
                <label for="password" class="label-2">Password</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="password" class="text-box"><br>
                <button type="submit" id="login" class="button">Sign In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the developer console?

Comment: You put the click handler on the H1 tag, click the word "Login" above in your example and it works...

Comment: @skyline3000 — They already said that (including the fact it works in the live demo here) in the question.

Comment: @bjelleklang Uncaught ReferenceError: loginDetails is not defined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External JS is added with `<script src="..."></script>` and not with a `<link>` element.

If you have run your code through [a validator](https://validator.nu/), it would have highlighted your error.

Answer (score -1):

Hey Try this code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Screen</title>
    <link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="login.js">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 onclick="loginDetails()">Login</h1>
        <form>
            <label for="username" class="label-1">Username</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="text-box"><br>
            <label for="password" class="label-2">Password</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="password" class="text-box"><br>
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="button">Sign In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
       function loginDetails(){
           alert('You Clicked on H1!')
       }
    </script>
</body>
```

---

#### Output :

[image: output]

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer (and fails to remove the code which caused the problem in the first place).

Comment: i put all code in once because i think thats easy to copy and check for you.
if this example is not working in your system then XD there is issue in your system.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your code works (current code snippet).

A better way would be by removing "onclick" attribute and creating event listener.

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
h1.addEventListener('click', loginDetails);
```

Comment: "Actually, your code works (current code snippet)." — No, it doesn't. Please note that the question explicitly says: "On the snippet below, it works just fine. But when I try it on Chrome, it doesn't do anything.".

Comment: Answers are supposed to answer the question, not **just** suggest general code quality improvements. If you can't reproduce the problem, the appropriate place to say so is in a *comment* (where you can also suggest code quality improvements).